# Where in Android source does the system look for and download OTA updates?

Tags: android, android-source, ota

I am looking for a reference to the source code where Android searches for and applies OTA updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTA updates are not part of the Android Open Source Project.  OTA updates are different for all devices and manufacturers implying that each has it's own OTA mechanism.

Comment: References that you have for a build would be greatly appreciated so I can understand where this occurs.  I have the kernel source code checked out